# JCheckboxMenuItem not working as expected

Tags: java, swing

I have create a popup menu and on right click in a panel the menu is displayed. But when i click the menu item the checkbox doesnt get selected. 
Here is the code:

```
public class DebugMenu extends JPopupMenu implements ActionListener{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("inside action");
      AbstractButton aButton = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();
      System.out.println(aButton.getText() +" " +aButton.getModel().isSelected());
      aButton.getModel().setSelected(!aButton.getModel().isSelected());
}

public DebugMenu(){
    JMenuItem menuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("2");

    add(menuItem);
    menuItem.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("1");
    add(menuItem);
    menuItem.addActionListener(this);
}
```

}

And the Panel class

public class TestPanel implements MouseListener{

```
public TestPanel(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEST");
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.addMouseListener(TestPanel.this);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new TestPanel();


}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    DebugMenu menu = new DebugMenu();
     if(e.isPopupTrigger()){
         System.out.println("trigger");
         menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
     }              
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    DebugMenu menu = new DebugMenu();
     if(e.isPopupTrigger()){
         System.out.println("trigger");
         menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
     }


}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    DebugMenu menu = new DebugMenu();
     if(e.isPopupTrigger()){
         menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
     }

}
```

}

what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out ...  I should not be creating the DebugMenu object inside the mouseEvents...

Answer (score 0):

Well I imagine that `aButton.isSelected()` returns true when you have clicked on it, so that the negation turns off the selection. Try using this instead:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  ((JCheckBoxMenuItem) e.getSource()).setSelected(true);
}
```

Comment: Too bad you can use .isSelected() to toggle the checkmark… it always returns true (I guess because you just "selected" the menu (with the mouse) to click on it.). Anyone know how to make it toggle the checkmark on/off on each click?